# How to check if PECL extension is present?

Tags: php, pecl

How do I from PHP code if a PECL extension is installed or not?

I want gracefully handle the case when an extension is not installed.

Comment: what about [extension_loaded](http://php.net/manual/de/function.extension-loaded.php)?

Comment: @redreggae, what about you write it as an answer? :)

Comment: can also use the ReflectionExtension class. Added that to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple different ways. You can just check for the existence of the class, or even a function: [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php), [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), and [`get_extension_funcs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-extension-funcs.php):

```
<?php
if( class_exists( '\Memcached' ) ) {
    // Memcached class is installed
}

// I cant think of an example for `function_exists`, but same idea as above

if( get_extension_funcs( 'memcached' ) === false ) {
    // Memcached isn't installed
}
```

You can also get super complicated, and use [`ReflectionExtension`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionextension.php). When you construct it, it will throw a [`ReflectionException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionexception.php). If it doesnt throw an exception, you can test for other things about the extension (like the version).

```
<?php
try {
    $extension = new \ReflectionExtension( 'memcached' );
} catch( \ReflectionException $e ) {
    // Extension Not loaded
}

if( $extension->getVersion() < 2 ) {
    // Extension is at least version 2
} else {
    // Extension is only version 1
}
```

Comment: Why the backslash on the class name?

Comment: For namespaces, if your in a namespaces environment

Comment: Interesting. Did not know about that one.

Comment: @Prof.Falken I realize now, that the forward slash isnt important. In strings, the first slash isnt required

Answer (score 9):

I think the normal way would be to use [extension-loaded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

```
if (!extension_loaded('gd')) {
    // If you want to try load the extension at runtime, use this code:
    if (!dl('gd.so')) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that dl() thing about?  Not really necessary right? Also, what if the code is running on Windows, no *.so* there right?

Comment: `dl` is for loading the extension at runtime

Comment: OK. I am not very fond of that.

Answer (score 7):

[get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) fits the bill.

Use like this:

```
$ext_loaded = in_array('redis', get_loaded_extensions(), true);
```

Comment: strange that this would work for you when `get_extension_funcs` wouldnt. For the record, using `class_exists` is usually the norm for doing things like this, but thats for showing me another way :)

Comment: @Ascherer, yes, I guess *class_exists* is more elegant, since it cares not about implementation details. I think I will use that in my production code. Nevertheless, it's good to know how to check for extensions. I think get_extension_funcs did not work because redis only exposes a class, no functions.

Comment: very true :) couldnt agree more

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [get_extension_funcs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-extension-funcs.php)?

Comment: No, was not aware of that. Interestingly, it seems to work for xdebug, but not for redis nor v8js.