# Why am I not able to use PHP pecl_http extension I have compiled and loaded?

Tags: php, http, php-extension, pecl

I am having very big troubles in running PHP PECL extension pecl_http (https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and PHP 5.6.13.

The situation is the following: I have compiled and loaded both the pecl_http extension and the dependencies raphf and propro, but still I am not able to run any code from the extension. If I try to instantiate objects or invoke functions I alway get "not found" erros like the following:

```
$  ./php -r "new HttpUrl();"
Fatal error: Class 'HttpUrl' not found in Command line code on line 1
```

I can say that the extensions (http, propro and raphf) are all loaded because if i try to enable them in the php.ini (e.g., extension=http.so) it gives me a warning saying that extensions are already loaded.

I tried two ways, and they both seem not to be working.

1) I compiled first PHP and then tried to install the extensions using *pecl install http://link_to_extension*. It automatically installed the dependancies. This method did not work.

2) I recompiled PHP, compiling the Http pecl extension and the dependencies statically into the PHP src, as the documentation describes (http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.static.php).

The result, is that I am in the situation I described at start: the extensions are loaded but I cannot invoke pecl_http methods/functions/objects.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/16613068/1301994

Comment: Ensure the packages are loaded by inspecting the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering. I can confirm that from phpinfo() the extension appears to be loaded. Here is the excerpt:

http

HTTP Support => enabled
Extension Version => 2.5.2
Used Library => Compiled => Linked
libz => 1.2.8 => 1.2.8
libcurl => 7.44.0 => 7.44.0
libevent => disabled => disabled
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
http.etag.mode => crc32b => crc32b

I have also tried to check it runtime using extension_loaded(), as suggested in the post referenced by Mike, and it returns true. Thus, it's loaded!!!
Really no idea...

Comment: WA! It works!! Can you explain me why?! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You've installed [v2 of pecl_http](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http).